# In Meteor: how does new Mongo.collection('name') function if it already exists on server?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In the Meteor documents it says

> On the server (if you do not specify a connection), a collection with that name is created on a backend Mongo server.

If there already is a collection with that name on the server, I assume then it merely opens it? Or in Mongo is collection != database, with the latter being the persistent entity on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server, `new Mongo.Collection()` loads the Mongo collection.

On the client, the same loads the in-browser Mini-Mongo collection.

Unless you have the `autopublish` package as part of your project, you must use `Meteor.publish()`, `connection.allow()`, and `Meteor.subscribe()` methods.

If you create a collection on the client without a name: `new Mongo.Collection(null)`, it will not be synchronized with the server at all.

If a client side collection doesn't have a corresponding server collection, it will cause an error `Method Not Found`.

Answer (score 3):

Typically MongoDB only creates collections when you perform writes on a collection that does not exist, but you can create a collection explicitly.  `Mongo.collection('name')` will create the `name` collection if it does not exist.  Otherwise it does nothing, but if you perform write operations on the collection they will still persist.

In other words this behavior shouldn't have a tremendous impact on you.  You will be able to use the collection even if it does not exist yet because Meteor will create it for you.